# How to mock axios with cookieJarSupport with jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

Here is my code that works fine

```
const axios = require('axios')
const axiosCookieJarSupport = require('axios-cookiejar-support').default
const tough = require('tough-cookie')

axiosCookieJarSupport(axios)

async function getData() {
  let cookieJar = new tough.CookieJar()

  try {
    await axios.post({ jar: cookieJar, withCredentials: true, url: '/user' })
    const data = await axios.post({ jar: cookieJar, withCredentials: true, url: '/token' })

    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return error
  }
}

module.exports.getData = getData
```

And here is my Jest test:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const getData = require('../getData');

jest.mock("axios");

test('test axios and return data', async () => {
  axios.post.mockImplementation((options) => {
    switch (options.url) {
      case '/user':
        return Promise.resolve({ user: 'John' });
        break;
      case ORMB_URL:
        return Promise.resolve({ token: 'testtoken' });
        break;
      default:
        return Promise.reject(new Error('not found'))
    }
  });

  const data = await getData.getData();
  console.log(data);
})
```

Now, Jest fails in line:

```
axios.post.mockImplementation((options) => {
```

with error:

```
TypeError: axios.post.mockImplementation is not a function
```

It seems working if I comment this line in source:

```
axiosCookieJarSupport(axios)
```

But this is now what I need.. All other calls will fail with this line commented.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm suffering exactly the same problem, some test case files are working and others failed with the same error even the code is almost the same. Everything works if I remove that `axiosCookieJarSupport(axios)`. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.post = jest.fn().mockImplementation((options) => { 
    switch (options.url) {
      case '/user':
        return Promise.resolve({ user: 'John' });
        break;
      case ORMB_URL:
        return Promise.resolve({ token: 'testtoken' });
        break;
      default:
        return Promise.reject(new Error('not found'))
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

`axiosCookieJarSupport(axios)` mutates the argument `axios` by creating a new instance of `axios` *after* jest as mocked all the functions on the default export. This is essentially overwriting the jest mock functions. You could either mock the implementation of `axios-cookiejar-support` to return the instance passed, or you should create a new instance of `axios` and pass it to `axiosCookieJar` support to avoid side effects.